# Laravel 5 What is the difference between simple text in a link and link with blade syntax?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

In laravel, links are sometimes written as
`<a href="{{ route('login') }}"> {{ __('Admin Login') }} </a>`

And other times, written simply as
`<a href="{{ route('student.login') }}"> Student Login </a>`

- What is the difference between these two syntax?
- What is the advantage of the first syntax ?

Comment: Which part are you referring to? The `route(..)` or `__(..)`?

Comment: The __(..) part

Comment: [`__()` documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-__). It looks up the translation from the translation file if you have it defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `__` utilizes the localization system in Laravel and can display the text in another language if you have it set up.

You can read more about it in the documentation: 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/localization#retrieving-translation-strings

If you want your website in different languages you should use it, otherwise your better of with just typing it as plain text.